# Programmatically changing text of a SettingsActivity widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity

I am developing my first android app.
I used the wizard to create a SettingsActivity, which works fine so far.
Now I want to change in an input field programmatically: I am generating a string which I want to be preset by default in an input field.

This is my input field, it's its entry in the automatically generated pref_general.xml:

```
  <EditTextPreference
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:key="example_text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name" />
```

My question is: How can I access this input field in my code?
Usually I request UI elements using

```
findViewById(R.*.*);
```

I assumed here I could use

```
findViewById(R.string.pref_default_display_name);
```

but this only gives me null!

Comment: Did you create a string resource with the name of `pref_title_display_name`?

Comment: There is this in R.java:
public static final class string { 
//...
public static final int pref_title_display_name=0x7f050007;
}

Comment: This constant corresponds to the argument I pass to findViewById, but this method still gives me null

Comment: I mean, did you put one in `strings.xml`?

Comment: No, the entry exists in strings_activity_set.xml, but not in strings.xml. When I add it in strings.xml, the compiler points out that it's already definded

Comment: D'oh. I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Hopefully I got it right in my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you're doing, you can use [`findPreference()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)  to get the `EditTextPreference` object:

```
EditTextPreference pref = myPrefGroup.findPreference("example_text");
```

To get a `View` from this isn't as easy, and is often not necessary. You can try using [`getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) on it, but that may or may not return what you want.

If you just want to set the input value of the `EditTextPreference`, you can use [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) on it, as you would with any `EditText`:

```
EditTextPreference pref = myPrefGroup.findPreference("example_text");
pref.setText("Foo!");
```

You can have a look at what else `Preference` and `EditTextPreference` can do in the documentation provided, but there are some things that can't be done in the preference screen. (That's just a limitation of Android.)

Comment: Thanks! Where do you call findPreference(...) on? What is myPrefGroup? So far I only found deprecated methods, the trick might be to do it fragment-based

Comment: It's of type [`PreferenceGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html) or `PreferenceScreen`, both of which have the `.findPreference()` method. (Also keep in mind that prefs changed between APIs 10 and 11, which can make this a bit weird...)